# What are the minimum kubelet implementation requirements?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I’m looking for a breakdown of the minimal requirements for a kubelet implementation. Something like sequence diagrams/descriptions and APIs.

I’m looking to write a minimal kubelet I can run on a reasonably capable microcontroller so that app binaries can be loaded and managed from an existing cluster (the container engine would actually flash to a connected microcontroller and restart). I’ve been looking through the kubelet code and there’s a lot to follow so any starting points would be helpful.

A related question, does a kubelet need to run gRPC or can it fall back to a RESTful api? (there’s no existing gRPC I can run on the micro but there is nanopb and existing https APIs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably won't be a full answer, however there are some details that will help you.

First I'll start with related question about using `gRPC` and/or `REST API`.
Based on the [kubelet code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4a6935b31fcc4d1498c977d90387e02b6b93288f/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go#L160-L174)  there is a new server creation part to handle HTTP requests. Taking this into account, we can consider `kubelet` gets requests to its HTTPS endpoint.
Also indirectly seen from [kubelet authentication/authorization documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#overview), there are details only about `HTTPS endpoint`.

Moving to an API part. It's still not documented properly so the best way to find some information is to look into code, e.g. [about endpoints](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/bd239d42e463bff7694c30c994abd54e4db78700/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go#L76-L84)

Last part is [this useful page](https://www.deepnetwork.com/blog/2020/01/13/kubelet-api.html) where a lot of information about `kubelet API` is gathered

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking for...something to narrow down the scope. Thanks!